# How to setup Visual Studio 2008's add-in setting for Qt?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt

I installed Qt and see its tab from Visual Studio, but I'm getting the following error when trying to compile and run an example:

```
No default Qt version found. Please check your Qt Visual Studio Add-in settings.
```

I guess I should modify this:

[image]

Putting some file/folder from here on the path:

[image]

**Which file/folder?**

Comment: Did you buy any chance build your Qt with MinGW or download a version built with it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right.  From your snapshot, it would be the "qt" directory.  Basically where the actual Qt installation and source are.

It should have the following sub-folders in it:

- bin - This contains all the Qt binaries - QtCore... and all the Qt
  apps.
- config.tests
- demos
- doc
- examples
- imports
- include
- lib
- ...